# jQuery target nearest element on click event

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, toggle

I've found a piece of jQuery code online that almost does what I want it to do.

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.toggleMenu = function() {
    var menu = $(this).find('ul');
    menu.hide();

    $(this).click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      menu.toggle();
    });
  }
});
```

I can trigger the function like so:

```
$('li.grouped').toggleMenu();
```

The problem I have, is that when there are multiple dropdown menu's they all get toggled when I click on a list item. It should only toggle the ul.dropdown under the li element I clicked.

I've tried code like this:

```
el.click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  menu.closest('ul.dropdown').toggle();
});
```

But it doesn't do much.

The HTML structure is similar to this:

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="grouped menu-item">
      <ul class="dropdown">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li class="grouped menu-item">
      <ul class="dropdown">...</ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item">...</li>
    <li class="menu-item">...</li>
    <li class="menu-item">...</li>
    <li class="menu-item">...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can alter my code so it toggle's the correct ul.

Thanks

Comment: Your function searches for a `<ul>` element within the element you click. So you either need to click the right element or you need to change your function.

Comment: The function name is indeed a typo, one I did not make in my code editor (using different function names).

Comment: I don't see the problem with the original code. It should only toggle the `<ul>` under the `<li>` that you click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing code travels down through children to find `ul`s. `closest()` traverses the other way, up through descendants. If the `ul` you want to target is always a direct child of the `li`, you could use this:

```
$(this).children('ul');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the children of your clicked element and just toggle that.

```
$(this).click(function(e) {
    var $item = $(e.target).children();
    item.toggle();
});
```

Further reading:
http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Thanks for the link, and helping me. Appreciated.